# THREE.js : efficient way to update dynamic line between two objects

Tags: dynamic, three.js

I am currently looking to the most efficient way to update a line connecting two three.js objects (Meshes) , when either one or both of the objects get changed (position, rotation, scale).

- Currently I have a polling method for every such connecting line , that updates its start & end based on the transforms of the two end objects, but this can get costly real fast when there are dozens of lines.
- I could go with an event based approach perhaps, but this requires dispatching change events from every 3D object that changes.

edit:
 perhaps some sort of scenegraph based hackery would be possible, but the three.js scene graph is just a tree, so no multiple parents etc are possible

Any pointers or better/ more optimised methods are welcome !
Thanks in advance!